# Android OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: android, oauth, facebook-access-token, android-facebook

I had a problem when trying to access my status on Facebook via my own app.

When I'm trying to get the information of mine using `Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback()` method, it's running well. In this case, to get my status feed, I use `new Request(session, "/v2.1/me/feed?fields=message", params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback()` method.

But, I got error message in JSON feedback:

> An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

Here are my code :

```
public class TimelineActivity extends Activity {
private String TAG = "TimelineActivity";
String[] arrayStatus;
ListView lvStatus;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timeline);

    lvStatus = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvStatus);

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
              .NewPermissionsRequest(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_status",
                        "read_stream"));
            List<String> permision = new ArrayList<String>();
            permision.add("user_status");
            permision.add("read_stream");
            Session.openActiveSession(this, true,permision, callback);
    /*if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setPermissions(
                Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_status",
                        "read_stream")).setCallback(callback));
    } else {
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, callback);
    }*/
}

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {

        if (session.isOpened()) {
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("access_token", session.getAccessToken());
            /* make the API call */
            new Request(session, "/v2.1/me/feed?fields=message", params,
                    HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {

                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            /* handle the result */
                            Log.e(TAG, response.getError().toString());
                            GraphObject graphObject = response
                                    .getGraphObject();
                            if (graphObject != null) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "get data :success");
                                JSONObject jsonObject = graphObject
                                        .getInnerJSONObject();
                                Log.d(TAG, jsonObject.toString());
                                try {
                                    JSONArray array = jsonObject
                                            .getJSONArray("data");
                                    Log.d(TAG, array.toString());
                                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                                        JSONObject object = (JSONObject) array
                                                .get(i);
                                        Log.i(TAG,
                                                "id = "
                                                        + object.get("message"));
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {

                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    Log.e(TAG, "JSON error");
                                }
                            } else {
                                Log.e(TAG, "failed to get data");
                            }
                        }
                    }).executeAsync();
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
            resultCode, data);
}
}
```

what should I do?